# MIPS Branch Datapath

Tags: assembly, architecture, mips

I am programming a single cycle MIPS CPU and I am confused how the branch address is computed. Given this MIPS datapath diagram

[image]

Why is it that after the sign extend and shift left by two, the address is added by PC+4?

My main question is when I do the

```
 SignExtImm(instruction.imm) << 2 + (PC + 4)
```

I would be off by one instruction. Looking at my MIPS assembly Fibonacci test case that I wrote:

```
[0x004000a0]    0x00112020  add $4, $0, $17        <-- # loop label here
[0x004000a4]    0x0c100002  jal 0x00400008 [fib] 
[0x004000a8]    0x00000000  nop                  
[0x004000ac]    0x00029821  addu $19, $0, $2     
[0x004000b0]    0x22310001  addi $17, $17, 1     
[0x004000b4]    0x1632fffb  bne $17, $18, -20 [loop-0x004000b4];
[0x004000b8]    0x00000000  nop
```

Say I am at `0x004000b4` and the branch is taken

The instruction is `0x1632fffb`

So `imm val := 0xFFFB` and `PC+4 := 0x004000B8`

sign extend imm val ==> `0xFFFFFFFB`

shift left by 2     ==> `0xFFFFFFEC`

then `0xFFFFFFEC` + `0x004000B8` ==> `0x1004000A4` ==> `0x004000A4`

but my loop starts at `0x004000A0`

If I follow that MIPS datapath diagram, I am unable to calculate the correct branch address.

Comment: Your code is broken, your calculation is right. I have assembled that code and I get an offset of `0xFFFA` as expected. Presumably the loop label is on the `jal` not the `add`. This is further indicated by the presence of the `nop` which would otherwise not be emitted.

Comment: Are you using PCSpim? I get the correct offset of `0xFFFA` if I turn on `Delayed Branches`, but I am not allowed to do that.

Comment: @Jester, the loop label is on the `add`

Comment: Playing with delayed branches doesn't change the code as shown which already has the `nop` instructions visible. The offset in the `bne` will change depending whether those `nop` instructions are inserted or not, depending on the delayed branches, but in all cases, the offset should be correct. In the code shown, it's wrong.

Comment: why at datapath if I was in specific stage then we are assume it's done? I mean lets assume I have lw and add, then for doing add I must wait for lw till it arrives to WB stage.. why we are not waiting after WB ? because WB mean we are writing into register but we at stage WB we are still writing .